# Receive and log webhook post

Tags: coldfusion, webhooks, stripe-payments

I have an account set up with Stripe.com. I have configured a webhook for testing and am sending test posts to a cfm page that "receives" these requests. However, I am not sure that this page is doing what it should be. Currently, I just dump out all data. Below is what the page code looks like.

When I run the page locally, or call it directly on our live test site, I get an email with all the data as expected. However, if I set the page up as a webhook url and then get Stripe to send a test message to it, nothing happens - no emails. I see nothing in the error logs either. What could be going wrong here? Could someone perhaps recommend a better way to receive and log the webhook calls from Stripe? I am a little clueless here. Thanks

```
<cfsavecontent variable="local.emailBody">
    <cfdump var="#GetHttpRequestData()#">
    <cfdump var="#HTTP#">
    <cfdump var="#REQUEST#">
    <cfdump var="#FORM#">
    <cfdump var="#VARIABLES#">
</cfsavecontent>

<!--- Build Email --->
<cfset sMessage.messageType = "email" />
<!--- Setup other Email settings like to,from etc --->


<!--- Send Email --->
<cfset application.Communication.SendMessage(sMessage)  />
```

Comment: it sounds to me like Stripe is not sending anything to your application. Can you check your web logs to see if you are receiving requests at all?

Comment: @baynezy: The strange thing is if I set up a different webhook url and send the post from Stripe to RequestBin, it arrives there perfectly fine.

Comment: understood but have you checked your web logs to see if this URL is requested?

Comment: You should also add `cflog` statements to log to a specific file in the CF Admin for your review, and wrap the entire thing in a `try/catch` blog and email yourself the error if something is going wrong.

Comment: @DanShort: So it appears the request does come in. But, if I dump the struct using #GetHttpRequestData()# the 'content' field, which I assume should contain JSON data, contains binary data. Why is this and how do I read the JSON data out of the binary data? Thanks

Comment: @Cheeky - It is determined by the content type and request method used. [Check the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c11.html) for more details. Assuming you are receiving a UTF-8 encoded string, try: `toString(getHTTPRequestData().content, "UTF-8")`.

Comment: @Leigh: Thanks a million! The docs helped as did you. All that was required was a simple `ToString(getHTTPRequestData().content)`

Comment: @Cheeky - It is better/safer to specify the encoding explicitly instead of relying on the defaults. That eliminates the possibility that your code may break unexpectedly if your machine settings change.

Comment: @Cheeky - One of you guys should post the resolution as an answer. So it is easier to find than searching through comments :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure by now you already figured this out, but you use...

```
ToString(getHTTPRequestData().content)
```

... or to put it in a CF object...

```
deserializeJSON(ToString(getHTTPRequestData().content))
```